# Regression on a subset in R

Tags: r, loops, subset, stata

I want to run the same regression for different countries (i.e. subsets of my data). I did figure out how to do in R, but after doing the same thing with much more ease in Stata, I wonder if there's a better way in R.

In Stata you would do something like this:

```
foreach country in USA UK France {
    reg y x1 x2 if country == "`country'"
}
```

Simple and human-readable, right? In R, I come up with split and ddply methods, both are more complicated. To use `split`

```
data.subset <- split(data, data$country)[c("USA", "UK", "France")]
res <- lapply(data.subset, function(subset) lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=subset))
```

A more compact code would use `ddply`. But in this case, the model will be run for all countries. Can I choose just a few?

```
ddply(data, "country", function(df) coefficients(lm(Y~X1+X2, data=df)))
```

But again, I'm interested in knowing whether there is an intuitive, readable for-loop like in Stata?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options:

One way using `ddply`:

```
ddply( data[ data$country %in% c('USA','UK','France'), ], "country", function(df) coefficients(lm(Y~X1+X2, data=df)))
```

Using `lapply` (or `sapply`) a different way:

```
lapply( c("USA","UK","France"), function(curcont) lm(y ~ x1+x2, data=data, subset= country==curcont))
```

You could use the `lmList` function from the nlme package.

You could use lm directly (though this will use a pooled estimate of the variance instead of separate ones):

```
lm( y ~ 0 + factor(country) * (x1 + x2), data=data, subset= country %in% c('USA','UK','France') )
```

There is also the `by` function and `for` loops and probably other options as well.

Comment: wow - the `subset` options of `lm` in your second piece of code is what I'm looking for. Great answer!